# Форматирование текста python telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Можно ли как-нибудь осуществить отправку подчёркнутого или зачёркнутого текста ботом в телеграм?

Comment: А в самом телеграмме такое форматирование текста возможно?

Comment: Ну да, подчёркнутый - Ctrl+U, зачёркнутый - Ctrl+Shift+X

Comment: Предполагаю: `ret_msg = tb.send_message(CHAT_ID, markdown, parse_mode="Markdown")`, а в `markdown = "~~зачеркнутый~~ текст"`. https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/151880f3919e51692008e635781ef758560f3379/tests/test_telebot.py#L102 и https://paulradzkov.com/2014/markdown_cheatsheet/

Comment: @gil9red Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно осуществить с помощью **MarkdownV2**

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '__Нижнее подчёркивание__', parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '~Зачёркнутый~', parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Это описано [здесь](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [указывать](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/151880f3919e51692008e635781ef758560f3379/tests/test_telebot.py#L102) текст в [формате markdown](https://paulradzkov.com/2014/markdown_cheatsheet/), например:

```
markdown = "~~зачеркнутый~~ текст"
ret_msg = tb.send_message(CHAT_ID, markdown, parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Если возможностей `markdown` будет не хватать, то используйте `html`: `parse_mode='HTML'`